# Geocoding with GeoPandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

Im studing about how to use pandas and geopandas, and get some troubles.
This is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from geopandas.tools import geocode

class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DataInfo.objects.all()
    query = queryset.values('location')
    locations = pd.DataFrame.from_records(query)
    test = geocode(locations, provider='nominatim', user_agent="http")
    print(test)
```

But when I run the code it throw the next error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Are you sure you really want allt that code at the top level of the class, and not inside a method?

Comment: no, its just for test purpose. I just want run geopandas well